# ASP.NET Core - What is the best way to persist a model across whole application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

To start, I have an ASP.NET MVC Core application that acts as sort of a wizard where the user logs in, and starts building a "configuration" of data. Essentially, as the user goes through each page, they are configuring/adding different data to this "configuration". As they go through these pages, the configuration is saved along the way. The problem I'm having is coming up with a good solution of saving the progress of the configuration and persisting it across the application. Here is a very simplified version of a couple of my models and what I'm doing (without getting into too much domain detail):

```
public class Configuration 
{
    string ConfigName;
    CustomerInfo CustomerInfo;
    InputData Input;
}

public class CustomerInfo
{
    string CustomerName;
    string Company;
    string PhoneNumber;
}

public class InputData 
{
    int SomeNumber;
    int SomeOtherInput;
    int AnotherNumber;
}
```

So, in this case, I essentially have a Create page for CustomerInfo. The user fills out the customer information form, save it, and then is directed to the Create page for InputData, saves it, is redirected to another view, and so on. While this is happening, I need to keep track of the "Profile" that all of these belong to.

I've considered using a Session to store this, but I'm aware of some of the drawbacks of that, especially if multiple servers are serving requests - sessions get lost, etc.

What would be a better solution/best practice for something like this?

Edit: I should note that I am using a database right now to store this data. So for this example, I have a "Configuration" table that contains foreign keys to a CustomerInfo table and a InputData table respectively.

Comment: You didn't mention considering a database in your post.  What are your objections to that?

Comment: I edited my post to mention that I am using a database. I'm able to save InputData to its respective table, but I need a way of associating that saved InputData to the current Profile that is being configured.

Comment: I would use a database to persist the sessions across the potentially many servers.  Or better still, a profile table so you can give the user a profileId, which you would then use to associate the other parts of data...

Comment: InputData is associated to a profile via the foreign keys in your tables.  When a user logs in, the Session keeps track of who you are - in other words, it associates a profile with your current session.

Comment: I edited my post again. I think the use of the term "profile" was a little misleading. The Profile in my case, isn't an actual user profile. Rather, it's model of a bunch of different data.

Answer (score 0):

We've used session for user-specific data.  Since our application was single server (or in a multiple server scenario with sticky sessions), session worked fine for the job.  For that you need to evaluate what your situation will be.  Are you definitely using multi servers, or web farm, or single server, etc. to plan appropriately.

The other approach is store minimal user information with the authentication cookie (you can store additional data like the user ID) and then read it from the cookie and reload on postback or when requested from the DB.  I would recommend only store something specific to the user (like ID) and not try to store all of the profile data within the cookie.

Comment: Also, I think if session is going to be used - SQL Server mode is probably the best option as its the most reliable.

Comment: It's probably the most reliable - just make sure everything going in is serializable, or you will get errors.  If the footprint is small enough,and you are using a single session or sticky session with a proxy, in proc is usually fine too...